# Cannot get data from local JSON file

Tags: angularjs, json

Here is my code:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>

</head>


<body>
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl"></div>

<script>

    angular.module('myApp',[])

        .controller('MainCtrl',['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
            console.log('I am Main controller ');
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: './testfile.rtf'
            }).then(function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },function(error){
                console.log(error);
            })

        }]);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is testfile.rtf:

```
{
    "cities": [
        {
            "city": "Stockholm",
            "latitud": "59",
            "longitud": "18",
            "id": "sthlm"
        }
    ]
}
```

Why am I getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token \ in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at fromJson (angular.js:1333)
    at defaultHttpResponseTransform (angular.js:10635)
    at angular.js:10726
    at forEach (angular.js:321)
    at transformData (angular.js:10725)
    at transformResponse (angular.js:11577)
    at processQueue (angular.js:16383)
    at angular.js:16399
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17682)
```

I cannot find any error in the above. I would appreciate some help. I am running http-server in the corresponding folder and I have tried several different JSON files. However, I am always getting the same error!

Comment: Check if the url for testfile.rtf is correct or accessible.

Comment: your JSON is ok.. you testfile seems to be not in right place. See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yuh3btxDUcbFbIf5yYI7?p=preview)